# SystemEvent.TimeChange showing same time even timezone changes

Tags: c#, timezone

I have wrote this simple console app to test when we change the timezone manually on windows 7 using set date time window whether timechange event is triggered or not? The answer is YES it triggered but i am printing current time which is not showing properly..

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SystemEvents.TimeChanged += new EventHandler(SystemEvents_TimeChanged);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
```

Once you run console app and then try to change the timezone it always reflects one time change but then it somehow stuck to that time even if you change the timezone to different timezone or same.

Am I missing something?

to verify whether system time has changed or not i have opened command prompt and use date and 'time' command to print the current time which shows perfect according to timezone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the system time zone is being cached. You can clear this cache though:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
```

Put that just before your `DateTime.Now` call, and it looks like it works fine. (Works on my machine, anyway :)

EDIT: As noted in comments, it appears that in *some* cases you also need to call `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()`. I didn't, but I dare say it doesn't hurt to do so :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. I found the same about the cache. Solved.

Comment: Also don't forget to put CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData(); before TimeZoneInfo.ClearCacheData();

Comment: @user393014: Hmm... I didn't need to do that. What happens if you don't do that on your machine?

Comment: timezone did not update for me unless i added  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData(); as well

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question, but are you changing the *time*, or just the *time zone*?  5:00 is 5:00, the fact that you changed the timezone (and by extension 'moved' the computer an hour or two ahead or behind) won't change the fact that the system clock is set to 5:00.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` shows *local* time, which *does* change when you change time zone. (The system assumes that the clock has the correct UTC value.)